# Keycloak-connect with express, is there a simple Keycloak login method

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, keycloak

I am using Keycloak-connect, the **Keycloak adapter** for **nodejs**. In my express app, there is an `app.post('/routes/login')` endpoint that the login form posts to. In that endpoint there is an authentication method that I am trying to replace with Keycloak. That method just takes the `username` and `password` (and request and response object), authenticates, and returns true if the authentication was successful. Is there an equivalent I can use in the Keycloak-connect-api? I was looking but the documentation was rather poor for that adapter.

In the end I am trying to use my own login page to log in to Keycloak.

Maybe with `Keycloak.grantmanager.obtainDirectly` ?

Comment: can you set middleware?  e.g. router.use('/endpoint', keycloak.protect('realm:something'), ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 
`keycloak.grantManager.obtainDirectly(username, password)` like that way and return the token to client.

or you can use rest api provided by keycloak

```
let tokenObject = await axios.post(`http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/${realmName}/protocol/openid-connect/token`, requestBody );        
if(tokenObject.status === 200){
    accessToken = tokenObject.data.access_token;
}
```

Comment: thank you. I wish they had this in the official documentation for the adapter. If they do, then I missed it.

Comment: Do you know how I can get the login username and role of that user a similar way?